# How to Solve Getting nan Entropy in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, wavelet, time-frequency, pywt

Based on this paragraph of a paper about brain-computer-interface, I wanna extract time-frequency domain features using discrete wavelet transform and then calculate energy and entropy with the giving equation.

[image]

So I've chosen [pywt](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html) in python, and now I have the below code for getting wavelet and entropy from each frequency band ( for example I'm using D2 ), and [here](https://raphaelvallat.com/images/tutorials/bandpower/data.txt) is the link of data:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')

import pywt
cA5, cD5, cD4, cD3, cD2, cD1  = pywt.wavedec(data,'db4',mode='symmetric',level= 5)


Ent = 0 
for d in data:
    E = d**2
    p = cD2 * E
    Ent -= np.sum( np.abs( p * np.log(p) ) ) 
print(Ent)
```

But I'm getting `nan` for entropy for every frequency band. How can I solve getting nan value for the entropy of the wavelet?

Comment: Where is `data` defined? // Please post a SSCCE

Comment: data is based on DEAP dataset.

Comment: That may be the case but in the code you've posted its undefined. There's not much help that can be given without the entire picture of what's happening. I see no issue with what you've posted so the issue must lie with the code not posted.

Comment: I've updated my question and now I'm using a simple data than you can download it and use.

Comment: It looks like you are squaring `k`, and not `D_j(k)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with negative numbers in second frequency band's result from wavelet transform. The logarithm of a negative number results in `nan` using `numpy` and a `ValueError: math domain error` raised exception using python's `math` library.

BTW I think you've made a mistake in implementing the formula. I think this is the correct implementation:

```
ENT2 = -np.dot(np.log(np.square(cD2)), np.square(cD2))
ENG = np.square(cD2).sum()
```